# Facemesh not being shown on ARKit Facetracking

Tags: ios, swiftui, arkit

I am using Swift UI along with ARKit to track my face and apply a mesh over it. However all I can see is just the livefeed without any mesh being applied.

```
import SwiftUI
import ARKit

struct CameraView: View {
    var body: some View{
        ViewFinder().frame(maxHeight: 500)
    }
}

struct ViewFinder:UIViewRepresentable{
    let ARView = ARSCNView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    var metalDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARSCNView {
        print(metalDevice)
        ARView.session = ARSession()
        ARView.scene = SCNScene();
        return ARView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARSCNView, context: Context) {
        ARView.showsStatistics = true
        let config = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        config.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
        ARView.session.run(config, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
        let faceGeo = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: metalDevice, fillMesh: true)
        faceGeo?.firstMaterial?.fillMode = .lines
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: faceGeo)
        ARView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    }
    
    
    typealias UIViewType = ARSCNView
}
```

I have tried other child nodes like a sphere which appear just fine.